# Mesh Analysis with only current source.?

Tags: circuit-analysis, mesh-analysis, current-divider

**Can we use mesh analysis and get current in 1ohm resistor....and is not then why? **

[image: current through 1ohm resistor]

Comment: Ask yourself what if we shorted out the 3 ohm resistor. Would 3 amp still flow?

Comment: The answer is yes, you can. Just set it up in the normal way. You'll have two mesh currents and two equations. You'll know one of the mesh currents but you won't know the voltage across the current source. So it is still two unknowns, too.

Comment: I'm assuming you know how to do mesh. If so, you really should have no problems. If you need help setting how to set it up, let me know.

Comment: Assume counter-clockwise currents for the mesh, you find:$$\begin{align*}V_{I_1=3\:\text{A}}-R_{3\:\Omega}\cdot I_1-R_{1\:\Omega}\cdot \left(I_1-I_2\right)&=0\:\text{V}\\\\-R_{1\:\Omega}\cdot \left(I_2-I_1\right)-R_{2\:\Omega}\cdot I_2&=0\:\text{V}\end{align*}$$You know \$I_1\$. Just solve for \$I_2\$ and \$V_{I_1=3\:\text{A}}\$.